# what are all the operations that FFMPEG uses to convert from yuv420p to rgb bmp?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, rgb, yuv

I am trying to replicate in my own code, not using ffmpeg libraries, the operations that ffmpeg does to convert yuv420p to rgb. Initially I thought it would be inside the function: xyz12Torgb48 in swscale.c but doing some tracing , it looks to be in yuv2rgb.c  ff_yuv2rgb_c_init_tables, which I can not quite see it.

Comment: For starters, you need to know [what 420 means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#4:2:0).

Comment: the simplest way would probably be to just research the formats in question, and figure out what math is required for the conversion. _only after that_ should you look at the `ffmpeg` code - copying something that you don't understand is a recipe for misery and bugs.

Comment: I know what yuv420 means and have a code to read a yuv file and separate the channels. I already did some conversions using equations in the literature , but I need to have the same output as ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, since nobody came out with a solution , I am just gonna post that I found using 
valgrind tool=callgrind ffmpeg_g 
which is a version of ffmpeg with debug objects that showed me the functions being called and inside \libswscale\x86 there is yuv2rgb_template.c which seems to have the operations you do yuv2rgb , in assembly

````
 * Conversion is performed in usual way:
 * R = Y' * Ycoef + Vred * V'
 * G = Y' * Ycoef + Vgreen * V' + Ugreen * U'
 * B = Y' * Ycoef               + Ublue * U'
 *
 * where X' = X * 8 - Xoffset (multiplication is performed to increase
 * precision a bit).
 * Since it operates in YUV420 colorspace, Y component is additionally
 * split into Y1 and Y2 for even and odd pixels.
 *
 * Input:
 * mm0 - U (4 elems), mm1 - V (4 elems), mm6 - Y (8 elems), mm4 - zero register
 * Output:
 * mm1 - R, mm2 - G, mm0 - B
 */ ```
````